# custom iphone message screen To field

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, sendmessage

I have a requirement to develop same functionality in my iphone app same as in message app, To: field.

where user can type recipients and recipients are get added into search field .

any idea which control is it. or some tutorial related to it.

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Starting with iOS 4.0, you can send SMS messages from within the app. You can do it using the **MFMessageComposeViewController** class.

[Here's](http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/iphone-tutorial-how-to-send-in-app-sms/) one of the many tutorials available on the internet on how to do it.